# Sql Selection not working with WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql

I want to do a sql selection with a WHERE CLAUSE, problem is when I defined the WHERE CLAUSE, nothing returns, is there a problem with my code ?

The variable $id for the WHERE CLAUSE is an integer

```
    $request = $this->_db ->prepare('SELECT id, title, brand, content,price, DATE_FORMAT(addingDate, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS addingDateFr FROM product ORDER BY addingDateFr ASC LIMIT :start ,:end WHERE categoryId = :categoryId');

    $request->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $request->bindValue(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $request->bindValue(':categoryId', $id);

    return $request;
```

The problem show up only with THIS WHERE CLAUSE.
I get an empty result.

Thank you
I need help

Edward

Comment: WHERE clause order should go after the FROM clause, i voteclose this as this look like a simple typographical error

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your query syntax, `WHERE` comes before `ORDER BY`. Try this one:

```
$request = $this->_db ->prepare('SELECT id, title, brand, content,price, DATE_FORMAT(addingDate, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS addingDateFr FROM product WHERE categoryId = :categoryId ORDER BY addingDateFr ASC LIMIT :start ,:end' );
```